# Element.prop('scrollHeight') returns the same value for different list items in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to get the heights and widths of the list items. I have checked out various ways of getting height and width of an item, but none of them returned the actual scrollHeight provided by the element.

When I checked the scrollHeight through console, I get

```
[div.class-name, context: ...]
    0: div.className.className2
        accessKey: ""
        ....
        scrollHeight: 176
        scrollWidth: 276
        ....
```

So I printed them out using code below:

```
angular.module('app').directive('temp', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'link/to/template',
        replace: 'true',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element.prop('scrollHeight'));
            console.log(element.prop('scrollWidth'));
        }
    };
});
```

it returns

```
112 (height)
304 (width)
```

And this set of values is returned for EVERY list item in the unordered list. None of the list items have such height/width (even considering that some margin/padding values are not applied)

I need those values in order to update css. Is there any other way around it? Or Could you give me a hint on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are having the same issue and looking for a quick patch: I used angular.element which is a wrapper for jQuery. This might not be the best solution, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Give me more details about the requirement or else i think it's better to try based on window.scroll
   functionality it means  based on scrolling you have to apply your own css to that elements .